# Install OpenNi Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, software-installation, kinect

I cannot find install instructions for OpenNi Ubuntu 11.10 anywhere on the internet.  Does anyone have a link to how to get it up and running or how I can get started?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenNi for Kinect on Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/204317/openni-for-kinect-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Download the OpenNI package from [here](https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI/archive/master.zip)

Before installing OpenNI you must install the dependencies. The following are the dependencies

1. GCC 4.x

   ```
   sudo apt-get install g++
   ```
2. Python 2.6+/3.x

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python
   ```
3. LibUSB 1.0.8

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
   ```
4. FreeGLUT3

   ```
   sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
   ```
5. JDK 6.0 or above

   ```
   sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
   ```

Once the above packages are installed. Now install the OpenNI package

```
unzip OpenNI-master.zip
cd OpenNI-master/Platform/Linux/CreateRedist
./RedistMaker
cd ../Redist/OpenNI*/
sudo ./install.sh
```

> Reference: https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI

Comment: I've tried that a few times and it says Building Failed each time... I'm not sure what I am missing

Comment: which step fails? Can you paste the error in http://paste.ubuntu.com/